# Theoretical foundation for dropout in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, references, dropout

Can someone point me to a thorough theoretical foundation for dropout in training neural networks?

So far I have found only handwaving explanations (e.g. Goodfellow's textbook and the original paper) as way to approximate an ensemble model and many empirical papers.

Comment: here are my own 2 hand wavy explanations. a) for images, drop out corresponds to occlusion (at bottom level, and similarly at higher levels), so can be viewed as form of data augmentation. b) for sigmoids, weight decay pulls neurons to linear region; not for relus - you can view relus as piecewise linear approximators - splines, which are regularised by number of knot points, drop out encourages redundancy, ie having same knot points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropout as been shown to be an approximate variational inference, and variational inference is an approximation of the Bayesian posterior. See Gal & Ghahramani for more details or Yarin Gal's thesis.

**Gal, Y., & Ghahramani, Z. (2016, June).** Dropout as a Bayesian approximation: Representing model uncertainty in deep learning. In international conference on machine learning (pp. 1050-1059).

**Gal, Y. (2016)**. Uncertainty in deep learning. University of Cambridge.